# How to set the text of an NSTextView in Xamarin Mac?

Tags: macos, xamarin, nstextview

OK, from the "I never expected THIS to be the hard part" department: how do I set the text of a NSTextField in Xamarin Mac?

```
  NSTextView view = new NSTextView(new RectangleF(0, 500, 200, 40));
  view.StringValue = "Foo";
```

does not compile (no method "StringValue").  Nor does SetStringValue("Foo").  Nor does there appear to be any SetText method.  There's an InsertText method, but it doesn't take a C# string; it wants an NSObject (which makes me think it's not really intended for direct use).

Note that if I use NSTextField instead of NSTextView, I can assign to StringValue just fine.  But with NSTextField, the same code fails.

I'm experienced in ObjC programming on iOS, but pretty much a noob to both Mac Cocoa and Xamarin Mac.  So I'm sure I'm missing some obvious answer, but my googling hasn't found an answer (and the Xamarin forums are down today).  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the Value property?

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14870/how-to-add-text-to-a-text-view-nstextview-in-a-nsscrollview-from-ib

Comment: Nope, didn't see that one!  Thank you!

Comment: ...although it appears that Value doesn't work with an NSTextField.  It's weird that you don't assign text to these two (closely related?) controls in the same way.  But whatever works, I guess!